# (Rails) PaperTrail and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, spork, paper-trail-gem

I'm having trouble with [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) (auto-versioning of objects for Rails) being used with RSpec tests. Normally I want my tests to run without PaperTrail versioning, but there are a handful of tests for which I want PaperTrail turned on. I typically run my tests with Guard and Spork, and I can use things like `PaperTrail.enabled = true` and `PaperTrail.enabled = false` around a given test and everything works fine.

However, when I run the tests with RSpec, the tests requiring PaperTrail fail. To be more specific, it appears that while code in `before` filters can produce versions objects, code in the tests cannot. After a considerable amount of digging and tinkering and trying code snippets (I've tried [this](http://teamcoding.com/blog/selective_paper_trail_in_rspec) and [this](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#turning-papertrail-offon)), it looks like the best solution is to use the `require "paper_trail/frameworks/rspec"` line mentioned in the [PaperTrail README](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#spork).

Unfortunately, each of these keeps me right where I started—tests pass with Guard/Spork but not vanilla RSpec. This is in particular an issue because while I use Spork locally, our continous integration server runs RSpec directly.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow my issue was fixed by changing `before(:all)` and `after(:all)` behavior to `before(:each)` and `after(:each)`.

Answer (score 15):

PaperTrail now has documentation on tests with vanilla rspec

https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#7b-rspec

After including `require 'paper_trail/frameworks/rspec'` in your `spec/rails_helpers.rb`

> ... PaperTrail will be turned off for all tests by default. To enable PaperTrail for a test you can either wrap the test in a `with_versioning` block, or pass in `versioning: true` option to a spec block.